# How to upload a module in Spring-xd?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, hadoop-streaming, spring-xd

I am trying to upload a module jar into Spring-xd 1.0.1.RELEASE version, but this release seems not to have upload command. I found this command on github documentation for Spring-xd release 1.1.0 to upload a module jar in spring-xd.

```
xd:>module upload --type job --name pigExample --file <path-to-this-sample>/target/batch-pig-1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

But is says

```
Command 'module upload --type job --name pigExample --file /home/springxd/data/pig_scheduling/spring-xd-samples/batch-pig/batch-pig-1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar' not found (for assistance press TAB)
```

So for the latest release of Spring-xd 1.1.0 they have an upload option for custom module creation, but how to achieve the same for the version 1.0.1 of Spring-xd.

Answer (score 1):

This functionality was added in 1.1. Previously you had to manually copy your modules into each container's module directory structure.